# Prove that if $a,b,$ and $c$ are positive real numbers then $(a+b)(a+c) \geq 2 \sqrt{abc(a+b+c)}.$

Tags: inequality

> Prove that if $a,b,$ and $c$ are positive real numbers then $$(a+b)(a+c) \geq 2 \sqrt{abc(a+b+c)}.$$

This looks like a simple question. We can apply AM-GM twice to get $(a+b)(a+c) \geq 4a\sqrt{bc}$. Then how do I use that fact to get $(a+b)(a+c) \geq 2 \sqrt{abc(a+b+c)}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$(a+b)(a+c) = a(a+b+c) +bc.$$
We can now apply AM-GM.

Comment: You mean AM-GM.

Comment: Yes, AM-GM inequality.

Answer (score 0):

we get after squaring and factorizing $$ \left( {a}^{2}+ab+ac-cb \right) ^{2}$$ and this is nonnegative

Comment: The point is to show how you got to the result. Brutal force surely would not be a good choice.